# If $A$ and $X/A$ are compact and $A$ closed, then $X$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

If $(X,\mathscr{T})$ is a compact topological space and $A\subset X$ is closed then we know that $A$ and $X/A$ are both compact. My question is, does the converse also hold? If $A$ and $X/A$ are compact and $A$ closed, does it imply that $X$ is compact? I believe the answer is yes. If $\mathscr{C}$ is an open cover of $X$,  then we only have to show that there is a finite subset of $\mathscr{C}$ whose elements form a union which contains $X/A$. But I am not sure how to do this

Comment: @copper.hat I think $X / A$ refers to the quotient space, rather than the complement of $A$, though it would indeed be useful to state this explicitly.

Comment: my apologies for the lack of clarity. Here, by the forward-slash, I mean the quotient whereas the backslash means the complement.

Comment: What do you mean by $X/A$? $Y$ is a quotient space of $X$ when $Y\simeq X/\sim$ for some equivalence relation $\sim$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $X$ is compact.

Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $X$. $A$ is compact,so there is a finite $\mathscr{U}_0\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ that covers $A$. Let $U_0=\bigcup\mathscr{U}_0$, and let

$$\mathscr{V}=\{U_0\}\cup\{U\setminus A:U\in\mathscr{U}\setminus\mathscr{U}_0\}\,.$$

The image of $\mathscr{V}$ under the quotient map is an open cover of $X/A$, so it has a finite subcover, which pulls back to yield a finite $\mathscr{V}_0\subseteq\mathscr{V}$ covering $X$. $\mathscr{U}_0\cup(\mathscr{V}_0\setminus\{U_0\})$ is then a finite open refinement of $\mathscr{U}$, which therefore has a finite subcover.